# Graphing an ellipse on TI-nspire CX CAS

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, calculator

How do I graph an ellipse on a TI-nspire CX CAS?

I know how to graph an ellipse with the equation $$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2 }=1$$

but I don't know how to put coefficients in the equation on the calculator. For example, how do I graph the ellipse with equation $$x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$$

Comment: is this on-topic? Shouldn't this be on the particular calculators manual or something?

Comment: You could just graph $y = \pm\sqrt{(1 - x^2)/2}$ seperately

Comment: @Sabyasachi No, I've looked in the manual and online and found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

So with the new software update, lots of things have changed.
Turn on calculator. Hit B to go to graph. Hit menu, 3,2 to go to relation.
Type in equation $$(x−h)^2/a^2+(y−k)^2/b^2=1$$
as shown above.

Comment: I'm still confused why Amy's answer doesn't work on new OS versions. The calculator just silently refused to take them in the coefficient method but when graphed as a relation everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go the graph screen, then press the menu button. Press 2:Equation, then 6:Conic.

It will allow you to enter the coefficients of the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Go the graph screen, then press the menu button.  Press 2:Equation, then 4:Ellipse.

Edit:  Set the denominators to 1, and h and k to 0.

Comment: Right, I know how to do that. But how do I put the coefficient in front of the $y$?

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly, but you can set b to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$